# installing jenkins with puppet

Tags: jenkins, puppet

I did google search for "install jenkins with puppet" and found [this](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/rtyler/jenkins) so i followed the first instruction:

```
puppet module install rtyler/jenkins
```

and it installed it.
now I saw the next instruction, is it a must? I don't understand where I need to place this (no mentioning of it just mentioning the section to add) following section as instructed:

```
node 'hostname.example.com' {
   include jenkins
}
```

where do I place this above section? is it a must?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical puppet infrastructure, you have a puppet master, and puppet nodes. A node is a single server that runs a technology (Like a jenkins node, or git node, or web server node)  The master keeps a list of which modules are installed on which nodes, usually in a file called the `site.pp`

The instructions are telling you to install the puppet module on the puppet master, then inside the site.pp file on the puppet master, list the nodes the module is installed on. (In this case the node name is `hostname.example.com`).

If you don't have a puppet master, and are trying to run all these commands on the same computer, then you most likely want to look into doing a masterless setup instead.

The commands would look something like this.

```
puppet module install rtyler/jenkins --modulepath=~/some/directory
puppet module install puppetlabs/stdlib --modulepath=~/some/directory
puppet module install puppetlabs/java  --modulepath=~/some/directory
puppet module install darin/zypprepo --modulepath=~/some/directory
puppet appply -e 'include jenkins' --modulepath=~/some/directory
```